# Nested template parameters and cv- and ref- qualifiers for function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a function which looks somewhat like this:

```
template <typename... A, typename... B>
void foo(Foo<A...>&, Foo<B...>&);
```

The problem is, I want it to accept any types of references (lvalue/rvalue) in both const/non-const versions for both arguments.

That's already 16 combinations, and obviously it's too many to write them manually.

The only solution I could see is to drop the nested type parameters:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
void foo(X&&, Y&&);
// + some SFINAE to enforce that X, Y are Foo-s
```

This is not acceptable, because I do need to know these nested types `A...` and `B...`. What should I do?

Comment: `template <typename A, typename B> void foo(Foo<A>, Foo<B>);`?

Comment: Which kind of different implementation do you do for those 16 combinations ?

Comment: @NathanOliver seriously? I don't want to copy/move.

Comment: Then you need an answer @Jarod42 comment.  How would you implement this where in some cases they are constant and in come cases you are not modifying that variable from the caller.

Comment: Why is SFINAE not acceptable? If you have access to `Foo`'s implementation you can add a public type alias to retrieve the inner type. If you don't, I think it's unlikely that the inner type isn't exposed somehow, and could be a defect in the library you're using considering your use case.

Comment: "The body of the function is exactly the same for all versions." -> Hence, arguments by const reference (unless the const Foo has a mutable member)

Comment: @DieterLücking your statement contradicts the purpose of perfect forwarding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accept arguments by taking forwarding-references and pass their types separately, wrapped in a helper type, `tag`.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename> struct tag {};

template <typename X, typename Y, typename... A, typename... B>
void foo(X&& x, Y&& y, tag<Foo<A...>>, tag<Foo<B...>>)
{
    // handle x and y
}

template <typename X, typename Y>
void foo(X&& x, Y&& y)
{
    return foo(std::forward<X>(x), std::forward<Y>(y)
             , tag<typename std::decay<X>::type>{}
             , tag<typename std::decay<Y>::type>{});
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfc06d4e4a386a59)